# how to detect internet connectivity in ionic 5

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on an android app and I want to detect when my internet connection is available and not with this ionic plugin, `cordova-plugin-network-information`but when i ran this command `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information` in my command prompt i got this error

```
Unexpected token   in JSON at position 0
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.    
        cordova.cmd plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information exited with exit code 1.    
        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

even when i added the `--verbose` to it, i still got the same error i am using windows 10, please how can i resolve this

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The plugin gives you a lot of additional information about the nature of the connection, the strength of the signal, etc. But depending on your use case you may just try adding simple online/offline detection functionality using Web APIs:

connectivity.provider.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, fromEvent, merge, of} from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ConnectivityProvider {

  public appIsOnline$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor() {

    this.initConnectivityMonitoring();

  }

  private initConnectivityMonitoring() {

    if (!window || !navigator || !('onLine' in navigator)) return;

    this.appIsOnline$ = merge(
      of(null),
      fromEvent(window, 'online'),
      fromEvent(window, 'offline')
    ).pipe(map(() => navigator.onLine))

  }

}
```

This way you have this code working across both hybrid builds and PWA and also avoid additional binary functionality concerns.

This provider can be imported in a component, injected via the constructor and then subscribed to the stream of boolean events:

```
this.connectivityProvider.appIsOnline$.subscribe(online => {

    console.log(online)

    if (online) {

        // call functions or methods that need to execute when app goes online (such as sync() etc)

    } else {

        // call functions on network offline, such as firebase.goOffline()

    }

})
```

Here is stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-z34sqf

So if you use Chrome's dev tools performance tab and simulate online/offline it works pretty reliably:
[image]

Comment: i got this error `core.js:6228 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at new AppComponent (app.component.ts:24)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.AppComponent_Factory [as factory] (ɵfac.js? [sm]:1)`

Comment: which hook are you calling the .subscribe from? seems like app.component calls it before it has been initialized. i will update answer

Comment: So the issue was that I omitted ({ providedIn: 'root' }) in the injectable decorator. See that I added it above. Tested and it works.

Comment: yes it worked, but how can i do it so that when every their is a network change, a function will be called

Comment: what i meant is that, when i first load the app, it will give me the network status, but if the network disconnects, it would not tell me when the network goes offline, i need it to be able to detect anytime the network is online or offline, not just when the app first loads but even afterward

Comment: But that is exactly how subscription works - you subscribe to the connectivity status (online = true and offline = false). As you see in the code the fromEvent operator creates observable of connection status. So you can initiate methods depending on such status

Comment: but it didn't work like that in my app, when i disconnect it, it didn't console.log anything

Comment: Hmm, I just tested the stackblitz app I added in the answer with dev tools and the code works reliably. https://ionic-angular-v5-z34sqf.stackblitz.io Can you share how exactly you perform disconnect?

Comment: I subscribed everywhere I would need to know whether online or not, like right before checkout or whenever I need to make to "phone home" to the database, etc.  Also would like to say @SergeyRudenko that this is an excellent piece of code.

Comment: Hi, @Sergey Rudenko Thanks for the amazing answer!. I'm having an issue when I try to generate alert messages in 2 languages. it's working fine when I'm inside the app, but when I go outside the app come inside, the alert messages shows in both two languages, without following the conditions. How can I solve it?

Comment: @PrabhashiBuddhima can you create specific question here and reference your context in full with more code if possible. I would take a look.

Comment: "disconnection" does not work on device or emulator

Answer (score 1):

I would update Ionic: `npm update -g ionic`

I still prefer to:

```
npm uninstall -g ionic 
npm install -g ionic
```

You can also generate a new project and install the: `cordova-plugin-network-information` and see if it runs without any issue, then you can compare the files to see if there is something different: `package.json`, `tsconfig.json`, etc

OR, you you can install Capacitor version of the plugin, it's possible to use both Cordova and Ionic Native plugins altogether:

```
npm install cordova-plugin-network-information
npm install @ionic-native/network
ionic cap sync
```